# Why got Object when use map to get length of each string element

Tags: java, java-stream

I am learning Java 8. So I write code like this:

```
@Test
public void getLengthOfEachString() throws Exception {
    String[] strings = {"I", "am", "IronMan"};
    Object[] lengthOfStrings = Arrays.stream(strings).map(String::length).toArray();
    assertThat(lengths, is(new int[]{1, 2, 7}));
}
```

I found `lengthOfStrings` can't be `int[]`
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the types do not match, you can fix by mapping to `int` instead of `Object` (and then `int[]` instead of `Object[]`). Change

```
Object[] lengthOfStrings = Arrays.stream(strings).map(String::length).toArray();
assertThat(lengths, is(new int[]{1, 2, 7}));
```

to (and don't forget the variable names need to match) something like

```
int[] lengthOfStrings = Arrays.stream(strings).mapToInt(String::length).toArray();
assertThat(lengthOfStrings, is(new int[]{1, 2, 7}));
```